# Refactor Higher Order Functions in Haskell to avoid passing Operators Through Several Functions

Tags: haskell, refactoring, higher-order-functions

I am trying to refactor this bit of code to avoid having to pass the same operators down through several functions.

The program that I am writing relies on several operators to be passed in at the top level in order to reuse code in lower layers. A simplified example of the pattern that I am using is:

```
add' = higherOrder (+)
subtract' = higherOrder (-)

higherOrder operator a b c d = d + someLowerFunction operator a b c
someLowerFunction operator a b c = c + someEvenLowerFunction a b operator
someEvenLowerFunction a b operator = operator a b
```

where the useful functions that are intended to be called are `add'` and `subtract'` and `higherOrder`, `someLowerFunction`, and `someEvenLowerFunction` is merely there to deduplicate the code that is common between the two exposed functions.

Is there some way to keep the benefits of this code (namely, that `higherOrder`, `someLowerFunction`, and `someEvenLowerFunction` can be reused) without having to pass `operator` over and over again? I have attempted to get creative with algebraic data types to make this happen but have so far not gotten good results.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here. I can't figure out what unpleasant code you've had to write, and what beautiful code you wish you had instead.

Comment: `higherOrder operator a b = a \`operator\` b` is equivalent to `higherOrder = id`. Also, your `operator` and `equation` are equivalent.

Comment: What's the actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back at this question, it is essentially one about moving behavior down closer to where the differences occur. Taking heavy inspiration from @chi's answer above (thank you @chi!), I have arrived at this as the smallest change to get the desired effect:

```
data Operator = Add | Sub

add' = higherOrder Add
subtract' = higherOrder Sub

higherOrder :: Operator -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
higherOrder operator a b c d = d + someLowerFunction operator a b c

someLowerFunction :: Operator -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
someLowerFunction operator a b c = c + someEvenLowerFunction a b operator

someEvenLowerFunction :: Int -> Int -> Operator -> Int
someEvenLowerFunction a b Add = a + b
someEvenLowerFunction a b Sub = a - b
```

Notably, I am still passing the operator down, but in the case where there are multiple operators that need to be passed, they can all be replaced with just the algebraic data type that allows this later matching.

As a more general comment, having the code this entwined is a bit of a smell. The fact that there is so much shared, except for a small difference later on shows that there should be some higher generalization that can be used to get around the problem entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand your question, but I guess you want something similar to this.

Define a type for operators, giving a name to the ones you want.

```
data Operator = Add | Sub
```

You can then define their semantics:

```
semOp :: Operator -> (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)
semOp Add = (+)
semOp Sub = (-)
```

Then, define a type for aritmetic expressions:

```
data Expr = Constant Integer | BinOp Expr Operator Expr
```

and a semantics for the expressions:

```
semExpr :: Expr -> Integer
semExpr (Constant a) = a
semExpr (BinOp e1 op e2) = semOp op (semExpr e1) (semExpr e2)
```

In this way, the syntax and semantics of binary operators is completely factored away from the definition of the expressions and their semantics.